# Contact Form Will not Return to Homepage

Tags: php, html, css, forms, contacts

Good morning,

I have added the URL location at the bottom of the PHP file, but still the page does not revert back to .index.html.

Very frustrating.

```css
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
     
    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "soultrainradio@outlook.com";
     
    $email_subject = "SoulTrain Radio";
     
     
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
     
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
     
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
     
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
     
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
     
     
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
 ("location:http://www.garyhornephotography.com/str/index.html");  

?>
 
<!-- place your own success html below -->
 
Thank you for contacting SoulTrain Radio. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

```html
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://www.garyhornephotography.com/str/index.html">
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>Submitted successfully</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good evening everyone, I have added a contact form to my website and when completed, the email assigned, gets the details, however despite my coding efforts and referring to google and on here, I cannot get the blank page thats confirms thanks to revert back to the .index.html page.

```css
<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
  $email_to="soultrainradio@outlook.com";
  $email_subject="SoulTrain Radio";
  function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo"We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo"These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo"Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
  }
  // validation expected data exists
  if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['telephone']) || !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
  }
  $first_name=$_POST['first_name']; // required
  $last_name=$_POST['last_name']; // required
  $email_from=$_POST['email']; // required
  $telephone=$_POST['telephone']; // not required
  $comments=$_POST['comments']; // required
  $error_message="";
  $email_exp='/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,
  $email_from)) {
    $error_message .='The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  $string_exp="/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,
  $first_name)) {
    $error_message .='The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,
  $last_name)) {
    $error_message .='The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .='The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
  $email_message="Form details below.\n\n";
  function clean_string($string) {
    $bad=array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
    return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
  }
  $email_message .="First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
 $email_message .="Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
 $email_message .="Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
 $email_message .="Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
 $email_message .="Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
// create email headers
  $headers='From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject,
  $email_message,
  $headers);
  ?> <!-- place your own success html below --> Thank you for contacting SoulTrain Radio. We will be in touch with you very soon. <?php
}
die();
 ?> ?><!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://www.garyhornephotography.com/str/index.html"> </head> <body> <p>Submitted successfully</p> </body> </html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome to SoulTrain Radio</title>

</head>

<body>

  

      <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
        <table width="500px">
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">
              <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
              <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="60" size="50">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td valign="top" ">
  <label for="last_name ">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="last_name " maxlength="60 " size="50 ">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="email ">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="email " maxlength="100 " size="50 ">
 </td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="telephone ">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="telephone " maxlength="60 " size="50 ">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="comments ">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <textarea  name="comments " maxlength="1000 " cols="50 " rows="10 "></textarea>
 </td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2 " style="text-align:center ">
  <input type="submit " value="Submit "><a href="http://www.garyhornephotography.com/str/index.php ">HTML Form</a> 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can just redirect in PHP - header("Location: http://example.com/index.html"); - just add that at the end of your script.

Comment: Apologies, so I just add ("location:.index.html"); at the end of the php script. Thanks again

Comment: Ahhh just realised, i forgot to add the word header...

Comment: Bingo. I had looked at the code for soooo long, I went code blind.. Header added, problem solved. Yippee Thanks for all your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append >

```
header("Location: somedomain.com/index.html");
```

to the end of your PHP file.